# Connector types or names

Tags: connector, power-connector

I am replacing my mains powered smoke alarm and the new one has a different connector. The old one (bottom of pic) has 3 flat pins/blades whereas the new one (top pic) has round pins. I've also show in the top pic the connector they supply with the unit.

Is there an adapter I could get that just connects to my existing connector and I can then plug in to the new smoke alarm and if so, what is the name of this kind of adapter? Or an adapter from my old connector to the new cable?

[image]

Comment: Check the package to be sure there is no adapter. Check the manufacturer web site. Ask at the store.

Comment: When I updated our smoke alarms, I bought some short adapter cables online. Not expensive. Sourcing such stuff is off-topic here, sorry.

Comment: That new connector looks like it’s able to accept either the new three-pin or the old three-blade detectors. Is it possible that’s an adapter? Just tossing that out there.

Comment: Thanks. The top pic does show the supplied adapter, But I want to avoid having to rewire anything and just use the existing wiring which fits the three blade prongs not three pins. And the pins are not equidistant to each other like the flat blades/prongs.  So basically I want an adapter to plug the existing connector into the new by just connecting an adapter if that's possible. Not looking for help sourcing, just the name of what this product might be so I can find myself. Thanks all